# Determine Angularjs Controller based on route params

Tags: angularjs

I have the following configuration for my route:

```
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'homeController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/main/home.html'
        })
            .when('/:section/:tree', {
                templateUrl: function($routeParams) { return 'App/Views/'+$routeParams.section+'/'+$routeParams.tree+'.html'; },
                controller: function ($routeParams) { return $routeParams.tree + 'Controller'; }
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
```

The view is loaded correctly but without controller and the controller function is not even called.
Is there any way to solve this issue or determine the controller based on route params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller function is not a function returning the controller name. It's supposed to be the controller itself.

Let's suppose the `tree` route param can be `Foo` or `Bar`, you just need

```
.when('/:section/Foo', {
    templateUrl: function($routeParams) { return 'App/Views/'+$routeParams.section+'/Foo.html'; },
    controller: 'FooController'
})
.when('/:section/Bar', {
    templateUrl: function($routeParams) { return 'App/Views/'+$routeParams.section+'/Bar.html'; },
    controller: 'BarController'
})
```

This, BTW, will avoid your application to cause an exception is the user enters something other than Foo or Bar in the URL.

If you have many similar routes, just use a loop to define them:

```
['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Brr', ...].forEach(function(tree) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:section/' + tree, {
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) { return 'App/Views/' + $routeParams.section+'/' + tree + '.html'; },
        controller: tree + 'Controller' 
    });
});
```

Comment: I know this syntax, however I don't want to have huge number of rules in my application. That's why I was trying this approach. Is there any other way we can reduce the number of rules in the application?

Comment: Use a loop to define all your routes. I'll edit my answer.